# Joining 3 Tables SQL statement

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

can someone please help me getting the correct SQL statement, I added a picture of the example and I need some help using the sql statements as a beginner..

I want the result to show exactly the same in a gridview..I attached a picture to explain..
appreciate any help guys!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you. I do not have a reputation to comment on Stack Overflow right now, hence posting as answer. Also, please post the table names, it helps to write query easily.

I have named the first table as ORDER, second as ORDER_SUMMARY and third as MODEL. Let me know if this solves your query.

```
SELECT O.CUSTOMER_NAME,
O.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,
O.DATE_OF_PURCHASE,
O.ORDER_BY, 
O.ORDER_NUMBER,
O.PALLET_NUMBER, 
M.SERIAL_NUMBER, 
OS.PIECE_PRICE 
FROM ORDER O
JOIN ORDER_SUMMARY OS ON O.ORDER_NUMBER = OS.ORDER_NUMBER
JOIN MODEL M ON M.PALLET_NUMBER = OS.PALLET_NUMBER;
```

Comment: shouldn't CUSTOMER_NAME be a part of the ORDER table so it should be O.CUSTOMER_NAME ?

Comment: You are right, I got confused with the table names. Corrected it.

Comment: what about PALLET_NUMBER ?

Comment: This is also corrected! I was giving you an idea of how to do this. You can try executing this query and see the results & modify according to your needs. Please let me know in case of any questions. Thank You :)

Comment: Alok I really appreciate your help man! I would love to mark it as answer but was wondering first if you can try it and preview result ?

Comment: Where should I try previewing it? Can you please let me know the link to this db? I should have tables to view the results :)

Comment: lol you are right! is there any free db that I can create sample tables online and try it?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ This is where you can build schema and try queries on it. But I am not sure why you are not using the db that you have with these tables already built in it? Do you don't have access to it.

Comment: I am reinstalling VS on my computer and its taking a while.. so this query is compatible with both MS SQL and MySQL ?

Comment: Yes, there is a dropdown in the menu bar on the top of the page, from where you can select whether you would like to use MySql or SQL or anything else. :)

Comment: and if I may ask.. for PALLET_NUMBER should I use OS. or M. and why ?